# Best way to output a webcal-download-url in twig

Tags: url, symfony, twig, protocols

I would like to generate an URL in Twig like this (usecase is subscribable calendar):

```
webcal://subdomain.mydomain.com/calendar.ics
```

The filename is given via `twig: global: ...` in config an `{{ filename }}` in twig.
My problem is, that using `{{ url('index') }}` the generated URL uses `http://` as protocol, but I need `webcal://`.

I also see no way to fix this by using schemes, because this protocol is special for just this case and none of the routes generated by that 'Index-'Controller.

I am searching for the proper way. Last chance would be to pass the hole url via twig-global.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There may be a clearer way, but I've successfully used something like this before:

```
{{ url("my-route")|replace({ "http:" : "webcal:" }) }}
```

This generates an absolute url to your route then replaces the scheme.

Comment: Nice idea. If there's no better (direct) way, than this is even better than my alternatives. Thx