# webcal:// instead of http:// in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, icalendar, symfony-routing, webcal

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161771/best-way-to-output-a-webcal-download-url-in-twig) on how to modify a generated url in twig.

What I'm missing is the routing side: I probably need symfony to be able to route:
`webcal://www.mywebsite.com/calendar` instead of `http://www.mywebsite.com/calendar`

to be able to share my calendar in ics feed format so that MS Outlook or Google Calendar can fetch it.

The ics file I produce gets properly validated and if I open it I can see it with Outlook. Trying on localhost MS Outlook cannot import it (add from Internet). Do I really need the webcal or is there anything else I'm missing?

**EDIT**

Tried the `schemes={ "webcal" }` inside annotation. It properly spits out an url formatted properly, but still Outlook does not like it (and Chrome does not open it if I write "webcal://..." but if I write "http://.." the url gets changed to "webcal://.." and Chrome tells me that it needs an external application to open it. I selected Outlook but does not work :(

Thank you!

SN

Comment: My first guess would be that your webserver needs to redirect the URL correctly to Symfony and Symfony does not care that much about the Protocol. Have you tested that?

Comment: Nop, and have no idea on how to do that. But see my edited question.